# Is it ok to have 'technical' events while modeling event sourced domain model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Currently I'm modeling event source-based domain logic for one of my projects.

It's based on **CQRS** with denormalized sql read side and event streams in a write side.

I've got a requirement that one of domain's entities should have some sort of `status` property (it's basically an enumeration). `status` can be changed in two ways: either by a user of the system directly or as a consequence of other changes in the system. From domain perspective only a user's change is a *true* change and thus *deserves* for its own event, other status transitions could be calculated from current state (other properties).

But. `status` property is vital in the read model. In addition system should provide current entity `status` and all historical statuses. But in order to do that looks like I need *technical* events for all state transitions which system would emit after calculated status really changes.

Theoretically I can avoid having those *technical* events. The only reason I'm considering this option is because of entity's change log, which now is a simple pretty print of related events.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the event-sourcing police aren't going to come after you.

Longer answer: in the short term, it doesn't particularly matter if you store calculated values in events, or if instead you simply write the antecedent data, and let the read model run the calculation for itself.

Things start getting complicated when you are dealing with a calculation that changes from one release to another.

Example: "It used to be that purchases over 100 USD require manager approval, but from now own that threshold is 50 USD".  So here we have a purchase request for 75 USD.  Did it need approval?  Well, that depends on which set of rules were in effect when the price was made.  Where are you going to capture that?

The usual take is that the event log serves not only to capture the inputs to your model, but also the decisions that you have made based on those inputs.  In other words, once you have the events, you shouldn't need the business rules anymore to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> status can be changed in two ways: either by a user of the system directly or as a consequence of other changes in the system.

Then you should capture this in your domain events. From a pure logical point of view, the fact that a `status` has changed is not dependent of the reason: if the user changes it then it changes; if the system changes it then it changes (the used will see it as changed, right?). So, from the status's point of view, it changes in any situation.

From your domain it's important why then `status` changed so you should capture this in the event itself. For example, the event could look like this: `StatusChanged(enum newValue, bool changedByTheUser)`.

Thanks to the Event sourcing, you can use this information (why changed) afterwards, in your [Aggregates](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) or in your ReadModels. For example, when the business rules regarding automatic-status-mutation changes, you can ignore previous changes made by the system, with a code like this:

```
if(!event.changedByTheUser and event.date < '2019-01-02'){ /* ignore it */}
```

Comment: It's also an interesting question about what approach is better: single `StatusChanged` event with actual 'status' value in its body or separate events per each status transition (bodiless). I prefer the latter, it seems more expressive to me, because I can express my domain changes rather than just status changes.

Comment: @MykolaKlymyuk yes, I agree